# A capacitor stores half the energy when charged from a battery each and every time?

Tags: batteries, capacitor, switches, energy

I understand that when a battery is connected to a capacitor that half the energy is stored in the capacitor while the other half is lost to heat or whatever other losses are involved once the capacitor is charged to the exact same voltage level of the battery.

Only a one time direct connection with a simple switch from open to closed that charges the capacitor up to the voltage level of the battery is what is being referred to. My question is does this occur each and every time?

Once the capacitor is charged to the voltage level of the battery then there should be 7.2 milliJoules of energy in the capacitor.

*If* the answer is yes that half the energy is transferred into the capacitor each and every time then what would the capacitor voltage have to be in order to *equal* 100% of the energy if it were to come from the battery?

I understand that in practice this will never happen, which is why the statement *equal to 100%* of the energy is indicated. (Meaning by some other method of charging means)

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fNJyK5.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68039/discussion-on-question-by-marc-striebeck-a-capacitor-stores-half-the-energy-when).

Comment: what does `half the energy` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your statement that "half of the energy being stored in the capacitor and half being lost to dissipation" is not very specific to begin with. It is true that the energy lost to dissipation is equal to the energy stored in the capacitor once it is charged, but only if the capacitor is initially completely discharged. In this case, half of the energy removed from the battery went to the capacitor, and half was dissipated.

As the initial voltage on the capacitor approaches the battery voltage, the ratio between the energy transferred to the capacitor and that removed from the battery approaches 1. This explains why the efficiency of a charge-pump DC-DC converter theoretically approaches 1 as the load current decreases.

Comment: How is this not specific? It's nothing but specific, it's a real world circuit presented with a real circuit schematic with that exact result. What am I not getting here? You just said that half the energy is lost, which I assume is happening in this diagram, as well as a real world application. Not talking about anything theoretical in any way, shape, or form.

Comment: Man, should I just answer my own question???

Comment: Your original statement is not specific because it's not clear what you mean by "half". I restated the question - as I understood it - to clarify this. The dissipated and transferred energy are equal and they could be described as half the energy removed from the battery, but only in the case where the initial capacitor charge is 0 (which is also not stated in your question).

Comment: Ok, ok. Fine enough of the nitpicking. I suppose you defined the question even more clear than what it already is. Seriously. So just answer it already, does this happen each and every time, after the cap is discharged of course in order to repeat the process, or even change the capacitance, or even the battery voltage. Then tell me what would the voltage on the capacitor be in order for **all** the energy to be there, and yes I know the battery can't really do that, and I specified that.

Comment: Does anybody here understand anything that I am asking? I need to know if half the energy that is lost and the other half that is stored is an occurrence that happens each and every time. The other part of that question is what voltage would it take to equal all 100% of the energy transferred? I specifically specified that I understood well that this would never happen, as I clearly put in parenthesis (By some other charging method), Man... !!!.... Beginning to get slightly irritated at this. I don't understand the down votes to this question, I haven't asked anything strange or weird here.

Comment: I can not accept an answer that has been changed therefore leaving my original comments to that answer unchanged. The question was actually answered in a more simplistic way in the comments section, which is sad because there is not a way to accept that answer in the comments section. This website structure is seriously flawed. The answer included a theoretical view in which the original question clearly stated it was not.

Comment: @MarcStriebeck "what voltage would it take to equal all 100% of the energy transferred?" - Voltage can't equal energy so this question is nonsense...

Comment: @immibis: This has already been solved, the voltage would need to be 16.97V. The question has been revised in a much clearer way in the question [Is the 50% loss of energy when charging a cap from a battery a set rule in stone?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337516/is-the-50-loss-of-energy-when-charging-a-cap-from-a-battery-a-set-rule-in-stone) The question doesn't require for the battery to actually charge the capacitor with 100% of the energy. All that was being asked is would 50% of the energy when doubled equal 100% of the energy.

Answer (score 3):

This is actually one of the paradoxes in the electrical circuits. Consider the following case:
[image]

The figure shows two identical capacitors C1 and C2. Suppose C1 was charged with a potential V and C2 was uncharged and we connected them as shown at t=0. Clearly initial energy of the system is \$\frac{1}{2}CV^2\$. But after charge redistribution we will have equal potential \$V/2\$ on both the capacitors because they are identical. The total energy now becomes \$\frac{1}{2}C(V/2)^2 + \frac{1}{2}C(V/2)^2 = \frac{1}{4}CV^2\$. Where do you think half of the energy went?
Answer is we did not consider all the parasitics and half of the energy is lost in the inductance of the loop. This energy would be lost in the form of electromagnetic field.
Similar is the case with your question work done by the battery is \$CV^2\$ and even if the conditions are ideal, that is there is no resistance, in the circuit you **cannot** transfer this whole energy into electrical energy some of the energy will be radiated in the form of EM field.
So the answer is you **cannot** transfer 100% energy into a capacitor.

**EDIT**
Since everyone seems to be questioning that the work done by the battery is not \$CV^2\$. Here is a proof:
For the circuit shown below, the voltage across capacitor as a function of time is:

[image]
$$V_C(t) = V_o(1-e^\frac{-t}{RC})$$
Here \$V_o\$ is the constant potential across the battery.
Thus voltage across resistor is \$V_R(t) = V_o e^\frac{-t}{RC}\$.
Energy lost in the resistor is:
$$E_{diss} = \int_0^ \infty \frac{V_R^2}{R}dt = \int_0^ \infty \frac{V_o^2}{R} 
 e ^\frac{-2t}{RC} dt$$ 
Integrating and putting the limits, we get,
$$E_{diss} = \frac{V_o^2RC}{2R}(1-0) = \frac{1}{2}CV_o^2$$
All this energy is coming from the battery. Thus, work done by battery is 
$$\frac{1}{2}CV_o^2 + \frac{1}{2}CV_o^2 = CV_o^2$$

Comment: I am not asking if I can transfer 100% of the energy into a capacitor in any way shape or form. I understand this is impossible as I have already stated in the question. I am asking if that were to occur, which I have clearly stated in my question, then what would that voltage of the capacitor have to be? Or more like what would the voltage have to be to make it equal to 100%. That's all I was asking, and obviously I know you can't transfer 100% when I have already indicated that half the energy is lost, in which I was asking if that occurs each and every time.

Comment: If it is not even theoretically possible how am I suppose to answer that. Imagine whatever you like should happen because I don't know.

Comment: It's not as difficult as it's made out to be. It's just a battery connected to a capacitor and that's it! Half the energy is lost in transferring the other half into the capacitor, as simple as that. I was just asking if this is a set rule in stone, without any changes made to the circuit. The other question was what would the voltage have to be on the capacitor in order to equal 100%? Or in other words, what would the energy be in the capacitor in order to equal 100%? 14.4mJ? This is all I was asking. I am reformulating the question and making an entire new question, since I feel forced to.

Comment: Final voltage cannot change will always be the same as the battery. So final energy Ecap in the capacitor will also be always the same. What could be changed is energy drawn from battery in charging the capacitor. I.e. what can be done (with a differnt circuit) is not to have 2Ecap drawn from battery but Ecap only.

Comment: @MarcStriebeck It's a *perfect voltage source* connected to an *ideal capacitor* using a switch that closes infinitely fast and wires that have no resistance.  At some point "simple" starts to be harder because you have conflicting idealized models.  A classic example of this:  It's not hard to imagine an unmovable object.  That's simple.  It's not hard to imagine an unstoppable force.  That's simple.  What happens when an unmovable object is struck by an unstoppable force?  It's just simple pieces put together, right?

Comment: The assumption that voltage is halved is fundamentally incorrect. There is no "law of half voltage"; no, instead there is the law "conservation of energy". In circuitry we model dissipative elements by resistances, and *that's it*. Since there are no resistors, there is no dissipation, and therefore conservation of energy still holds. Your hand-waving explanation of "radiative losses by parasitic inductance" is laughable: neither are inductors dissipative, nor is any inductor indicated in your circuit.

Comment: @Cuadue You are falling to the same pit I did previously. Take a look into derived Ediss. The resistance is cancelled out. So *regardless* of the resistance the energy will be wasted. In case of R=0 it is becoming non-physical in the terms of ohmic model, but then the EM effects are coming into the play , so that energy is being "dissipated" by other means. See [here](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capeng2.html#c4) and other results of "capacitors energy sharing" query.

Comment: @EugeneSh. your modeling of a battery as an ideal voltage source with series resistance is wildly incorrect, first of all. At the very least, use a capacitance in series with resistance. Secondly, ok now that I'm reading it, "non-physical in terms of ohmic model," I think I finally understand that you're trolling. Well played!

Comment: @Cuadue First of all -
 the answer is not mine, and I was the most active critic of it few hours ago. And yes, I suspected the author of trolling. But then I did my research and came up with surprising results (for me). this one is interesting in particular:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/35843/a-problem-of-missing-energy-when-charging-a-second-capacitor

Comment: @Cuadue If you would have read properly I said parasitic inductance, any closed loop has inductance associated with it, that is basic physics. I think what is laughable is your lack of understanding.

Comment: Why not mention Earth's magnetic field while you're at it, and the electrostatic potential of a human being to explain why it also acts as an excellent WiFi receiver? Draw the inductor in the circuit if you use it in analysis. If there are losses, draw a resistor. Your linked answer is *ALSO PLAIN WRONG*. What a world we live in.

Comment: Let me offer some counter-evidence to the princeton paper: the existence of efficient charge pumps. Riddle me this: how do charge pumps not have efficiencies less than 50%? Is Texas Instruments lying in their datasheet http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2665.pdf when they say "90% Typical Conversion Efficiency at 40 mA"? The principle of the charge pump is to shuttle energy between capacitors! Explain that one please.

Comment: I do agree that this answer would be better by either a) Removing the original answer and only providing the edit (which focuses on the circuit the OP wanted to focus on, rather than a different circuit), or b) Link the paper which argues that inductance can place a huge role in the answer (rather than just in the comments).  The original answer does look a lot like hand-waving, because the entire content is basically "you forgot some stuff... and some stuff matters."  The edit is much clearer, from start to finish.

Comment: @Cuadue: A charge pump that fully charges and discharges caps on every cycle would be limited to 50% efficiency.  A charge pump which alternates between connecting two caps in parallel to a 10V load and then in series to a 19V load, however, would only charge and discharge the caps by 0.5 volts, thus only wasting energy proportional to that 0.5 volt swing, rather than the entire cap voltage.

Comment: Is it also true then that you cannot deliver 100% of power into a resistor because wires? Just kind of, wires, they mean you cannot put 100% of energy into a resistor, therefore, you have to use integrals to solve this simple RC circuit, and everything you've been taught about RC circuits is wrong because *wires*. Ever heard of electromagnetic radiation? Yeah well, you'd better think about that before solving V=IR. By the way, V=IR doesn't hold because *wires radiate energy* So it's really V=IR/4. Wow! Where does that /4 come from? The WIRES!

Comment: @Cuadue you are wrong. Half energy is always lost in real circuits charging from zero volt a capacitor. Trying calculations with ideal source and ideal capacitor only brings in singularity. That model -yes circuits we work on are just MODELS always wrong to some extent- the model is not good enough.

Comment: To Cuadue's point: a "wire" as drawn in a circuit schematic *by definition* has absolutely *no* inductance and *no* resistance. It is a theoretical construct that by definition has exactly the same voltage at any point along it (just like an ideal source defines the voltage across or the current through it, etc.). If you're talking about a loop having "parasitic" inductance but it's not represented in the schematic, then the schematic is incorrect, plain and simple...

Comment: ...Saying that a loop must have inductance because "basic physics" and then not drawing in the distributed inductance is an abuse of notation. We ignore lots of things in simple circuit analysis when their effect isn't substantial to the analysis. But once less-simple phenomena become tangible, the model must change accordingly. Hence why you don't use simple "wires" to model e.g. transmission lines or other distributed elements in high-frequency circuits.

Comment: @Shamtam I was trying to explain what is usually missed in a simple analysis with two capacitors in parallel. I know I could have but I was trying to explain **what would go wrong** if you miss the inductor. In this specific case violation of energy conservation. I would have to explain the problem before giving a solution.

Comment: @sarthak In this specific case, if you were to just draw an inductor into the schematic, there would not be any radiation, and in fact, no losses. The circuit would oscillate indefinitely, because there are no lossy elements. Explaining the paradox is fine, but your explanation is incorrect. If you wanted to correctly depict loss due to radiation, you'd need to draw in an antenna and a load as well. I understand I'm being senselessly pedantic, but for those unfamiliar with the limitations of lumped-circuit theory, having "magic" phenomena that aren't depicted on a schematic is just confusing.

Comment: @Shamtam I agree inductor is lossless I should have also added the radiation resistance.

Answer (score 2):

> Only a one time direct connection with a simple switch from open to closed that charges the capacitor up to the voltage level of the battery is what is being referred to. My question is does this occur each and every time?

This will occur each and every time you charge a capacitor from a voltage source, with no inductance in the circuit, when the capacitor starts at zero volts.

> If the answer is yes that half the energy is transferred into the capacitor each and every time then what would the capacitor voltage have to be in order to equal 100% of the energy if it were to come from the battery?

This is a meaningless question. The capacitor voltage can't equal the energy because one of them is a voltage and the other one is an amount of energy. (also, "the energy" means *which* energy?)

Comment: The answer has already been solved quite easily in [Is the 50% loss of energy when charging a cap from a battery a set rule in stone?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337516/is-the-50-loss-of-energy-when-charging-a-cap-from-a-battery-a-set-rule-in-stone) The question does not require that all 100% of the energy has to come from the battery which is impossible. 12 V is 50% of the energy that came from the battery. What was being asked in reality is that if the 50% energy transferred into the capacitor was doubled then what would the voltage be? It would be 16.97 V was the answer

Comment: Sure but if you tried to charge it with a 16.97-volt battery, then 200% of the energy would be extracted from the battery and 100% would be in the capacitor.

Comment: OMG dude. There is no need to complicate things more than they have to be. The answer has already been given and solved. 16.97 V is what the voltage of the capacitor would be if the 12 V *or half the energy* would be if it were doubled. It is not necessary for the energy to come from the battery, which is impossible. This was clearly indicated in the question. Please reread the question. Thank you and good night.