# Is the 50% loss of energy when charging a cap from a battery a set rule in stone?

Tags: batteries, capacitor, switches, energy

This question is similar to [A capacitor stores half the energy when charged from a battery each and every time?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337487/a-capacitor-stores-half-the-energy-when-charged-from-a-battery-each-and-every-ti)
(And no it is not a duplicate it is different in that it has been made more clearer.)

What seemingly was originally thought as an extremely easy question was not well understood. So it has been reworded again to be even more specific. So not a duplicate question.

It is meant to be understood that a capacitor starts with 0J and 0V in it. Next the switch is closed in order to connect the battery to the capacitor in order to charge it up to the exact same voltage level of that of the battery.

There is now 7.2 milliJoules of energy stored in the capacitor.

[image]

I am only referring to the schematic presented, which works exactly like what the schematic portrays. This is a real world circuit done on the work bench. It has losses due to resistance in the wires, capacitor, battery, and switch.

It is not lossless and so it is not perfect, there are losses involved as mentioned immediately above.

Half the energy is lost in doing work to transfer the other half into the capacitor. In other words the amount of work it takes to transfer half the energy into the capacitor is exactly equal to the amount of energy stored in the capacitor. This is a well known fact of life and electronics.

In other words, if 2 Joules of energy came out of a battery, then only 1 of those Joules would make it into the capacitor.

**What I am asking is:** When charging a capacitor from a battery, is this 50% loss of energy and 50% stored energy in the capacitor a set rule in stone?

I am referring to this exact circuit only or any other similar circuit with different capacitance's or different battery voltages with the exact same process of simply closing the switch just one time only.

I am not referring to ramp charging, step charging, or anything other type of charging. No other components are involved or added into the circuit. Just a simple closing of a switch to connect the battery to the capacitor *only*.

I know that this is another question but it's directly related to the first question, I don't want to ask it in another question and risk having a duplicate question, which it shouldn't anyways.

**Other question:** *If* the 50% loss of energy in order to transfer the other 50% energy *is a set rule in stone* then what voltage would the capacitor have to be in order to double the energy in the capacitor to make it equal to 100%?

In other words, what voltage should the capacitor be when it has 14.4mJ of energy in it, which should be double or twice the amount of the 50%, if I am getting that correct at all.

It should not be inferred that I am implying that the capacitor is capable of receiving 100% of the energy transferred from the battery as this is completely impossible and preposterous with the given circuit, but only asking what voltage would the capacitor have to be in order to double the 50% of the energy transferred into it?

Comment: Apply the answers you have been given - especially the thorough proof.

Comment: I think the answer for the original question is a good one, no?

Comment: The answer to "other question" is 17V (12V * sqrt(2)).

Comment: Don’t create a new question - instead, edit/rewrite/add to the original.

Comment: The loss would still be true if this were two equal valued capacitors, one charged and one discharged, and the wires between them were lossless superconductors. Switch closed means Dirac pulse. Fourier transform says radiation over all frequencies of infinitesimally low, but non-zero, unit energy per Hz. Integrate and you'd calculate the missing energy. Get a bolometer and you'd find the lost energy.

Comment: History keeps repeating with this guy... VTC.

Comment: @Winny - It's not history since I am finding answers in reality that in no way match any answer presented so far for a real world circuit, why don't you just open your mind a little bit more before commenting on *set in stone* rules of electronics and physics and websites.

Comment: Textbooks don't have parasitics, your real world does. Anyway, this is a meta issue. You are not following the rules and guidelines for EE.SE.

Comment: Don't create a new question when you mess up a existing one.  Fix the existing one instead.

Comment: @ Winny - Ok you need to quit labeling every question as a duplicate question when it is absolutely not a duplicate question. And I would like an English translation for a *meta issue*. I have no clue what that is, and I suppose I have to be a genius to understand what that is right? It's a simple question.

Comment: @Olin Lathrop - Too late, I have already asked the question again, but it's not the same one. I don't see how I am supposed to fix a question that already has invested time by others in it, I would delete it altogether, but it won't let me. Pretty lame if you ask me, but you didn't, so it doesn't matter.

Comment: It's been made quite clear, with both questions that this is not some theoretical circuit that is lossless with super conductors or whatever, it's a real world circuit with losses which again, I made clear. It's a 3 component circuit and I am appalled that the question wasn't understood. So far there has only been one realistic answer that actually solved my question for me, I think it should be a role model to the rest of you. So study it.

Comment: @Mark: "*I am appalled that the question wasn't understood.*" If I asked a question and found that many expert readers could not understand it then I would question my ability to express the question clearly.

Comment: @ Transistor - Then word it better than me then. Until then I wouldn't really say anything anymore.

Comment: This is absolutely a duplicate because you are trying to ask the same thing you were trying to ask in the last question. Questions can be edited.

Comment: No you don't get it in any way at all. People don't understand simple questions around here because well, I guess they are too simple. Sure I could edit the question but it's already been ruined with other comments and answers that are already invested into the question. Anyways I have already tried explaining what the difference is and they don't care and claim it as a duplicate anyways. This had ruined my rep, and it was the world's simplest question. This question has been made more clearer and therefore answered in a much better and appreciable way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So the voltage in such a capacitor is the integral of current over time (\$V=V_0 + 1/C * \int_0^TI dt\$).

Right away we see the problem.  The *perfect voltage source* will force a voltage of 12V across the capacitor.  Meanwhile, the *ideal capacitor* will force the voltage to be 0V, and start integrating the current that flows through it.  The voltage cannot be 0V and 12V simultaneously.

Battery resistance to the rescue!  The circuit has resistance.  In fact, a good chunk of it is the resistance of the battery.  So we really have a voltage source, a resistor, and a capacitor.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fg1DEc.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

This is more manageable.  When you throw the switch, the voltage across the capacitor is 0, the voltage across the resistor is 12V, and everything is sane.  At t=0, 100% of the power flows through the resistor. This means there's current flowing, and the capacitor can charge.  This increases the voltage of the capacitor according to the [following equation](http://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/rc/rc_1.html):

$$ V = V_s(1 + e^\frac{-t}{RC})$$

where V_s is the source voltage (12V), t is time, R is the resistance (of the parasitic elements like the battery), and C is the capacitance of the capacitor.

Now we can find the current.  Since all the current flows through the resistor, and the resistor has \$(V_s - V)\$ volts across it, the current at any moment in time is \$\frac{V_s - V}{R}\$.

Now we can look at the power loss in the resistor: \$(V_s - V)^2/R\$.  Integrating this over time, we get
$$\int_0^T \frac{V_s - V_s(1 + e^\frac{-t}{RC}))^2}{R}dt$$
$$= \int_0^T \frac{V_s^2}{R}e^\frac{-t}{RC}dt$$
$$\left[\frac{1}{2}V_s^2Cexp(-2t/RC)\right]_0^T$$
$$\frac{1}{2}V_s^2Cexp(-2T/RC) - \frac{1}{2}V_s^2C$$

Now we're interested in "completely charged" which is what we get as T approaches infinity.  In this case, the first term drops out completely (because \$\lim_{x\to \infty}e^{-x} = 0\$).  The final energy lost across the resistor is \$\frac{1}{2}V_s^2C\$.

Now, when the capacitor is fully charged, It's [stored energy](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electric/capeng.html) is defined just by the instantaneous voltage across the capacitor.  \$\frac{1}{2}CV^2\$.  Note that when \$V = V_s\$ (i.e. fully charged), this energy stored in the capacitor is exactly equal to the energy lost by the resistor.

This shows that if you charge a capacitor with nothing but a real voltage source (i.e. battery), you must lose 50% of the energy (to heat).

Comment: Use `\$` tag to start and end inline MathJAX and `$$` for whole line.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks!  That's so much more accessable!  I didn't realize the backslash was needed.

Comment: Another trick is to put 's', 'm' or 'l' (small, medium, large) in front of the .jpg for the inline image or schematic. It removes the "schematics for the blind" look on schematics with only a few components. '...m.jpg' would be appropriate for yours.

Comment: I like your answer, but a bit too much quanterion for newbies asking for straight and direct answers. Not saying that it is quanterion or quadratic, but it can appear so to those who are just beginning to learn and who eyes don't glaze over from such formulas as those. Regardless I am accepting this answer as the final answer that was needed was included at the very end where *you must lose 50% of the energy*.

Comment: Actually it would be nice to answer the last half of that question. What would the voltage on the capacitor have to be in order for the capacitor to have double the energy of 7.2mJ, which is 14.4mJ of energy? 16.9703V?

Comment: @MarcStriebeck That seems like a very straight forward calculation.  Energy is proportional to the square of the voltage, so doubling energy means we must increase the voltage by sqrt(2), so you would be right: 16.97V.

Comment: @Cort Ammon - Again a very specific answer to a very specific question. Greatly appreciated! Ok so I see now how the calculation was arrived to. So basically just make the capacitor 16.97V. Thank you!

Comment: @MarcStriebeck When you say "100% of the energy," the question is "100% of what?"  In *any* charging circuit like this, you will have losses.  If you charge the capacitor up to "full" with a simple circuit like this, it will always waste half of the energy that the battery outputs.

Comment: That would depend on how it reached there. Surely that's the message of the integrals? A capacitor at 17V would be *discharging* into the battery.

Comment: Let's say the battery did charge the battery up with 100% of the energy *I know that is completely absurd and will never happen as it's impossible* would the voltage in the capacitor indeed be 16.97V? Would you agree that the voltage would indeed have to be that? Oops sorry didn't realize there was a reply before posting this. I deleted it in the previous reply. This is the actual reply.

Comment: A simple yes or no would be fine. No need for explanations of how impossible it is, I've already stated that it is realized that it's impossible. Basically what I am now asking is, Would the 50% when doubled in energy be equal to 100%?

Comment: I know it seems repetitive, I don't really care because I need to know this to substantiate something else entirely different and there's good for all involved so, if not that's ok, I think I've got enough answers to confirm for myself what it is that I am really seeing, in reality.

Comment: @MarcStriebeck If a battery charged a capacitor up to 14.4mJ, its voltage will be 16.97V, regardless of how you went about your business.  What ratios you wish to take in order to form your percentages is up to you.  It gets tricky to answer questions in the form of "Ignoring the laws of electrical engineering, can you give me an answer to this electrical engineering problem?"

Comment: It reminds me a bit of the issue they had with quantum mechanics and relativity.  They had a bunch of "self interaction terms" which went on to infinity.  They were able to argue that the magnitude of each term went down fast enough that they could just "normalize" the equations to get rid of the infinite sum.  Then, when they tried to fit it with relativity, the change in the shape of spacetime broke that normalization process and resulted in a model that predicted that all particles have infinite energy.  Not one physicist went down the road of "what if everything indeed had infinite energy"

Comment: Instead, all of them went down the road of "well, that model doesn't fit reality, so we'll stop trying to make sense of the numbers in that model.  Instead we'll focus on making new models which represent reality more appropriately."

Comment: @Corb & Ammon: Well it's not really that tricky, believe me. I'm not saying that a battery can transfer 100% into a capacitor and this is most certainly not the reason for asking such a question, especially if the question is merely a yes or no question of half the energy multiplied twice equals a whole, or 100%. The laws of electrical engineering have not been ignored in order to ask a simple question that doesn't need a 100% transfer of energy, so rest assured. Although what I can say is that I have seen some rather surprising things that don't really match to what has been said here today.

Comment: As a mathematically true statement: "if some quantity X is 50% of Y, then 2X is 100% of Y."  That statement can be made.  My concern is that that statement is too obvious, and I'm worried you may be trying to take away "If some quantity X is 50% of Y1, then 2X is 100% of Y2," which is only true if Y1=Y2

Comment: @Cort Ammon: Y1 does not equal Y2. Just ignore everything except the statement that is too obvious. There is only one question everything outside of that question does not matter. 50% x 2 = 100% is all that is to be concerned with.