# Are power systems that rely on batteries limited to 25% efficiency?

Tags: power, batteries, efficiency

In a system involving a power source that charges a battery, and a load that subsequently runs from the battery, are we limited to 25% efficiency at best?

Since charging a battery (or capacitor) loses 50% of the power transferred to heat, and by the same logic, another 50% while discharging into a load...does that not imply that battery systems of this type cannot be more than 25% efficient?

Comment: Where are you getting these figures (50% of power "transferred" to heat)?

Comment: YOu are going to have to quote your source for those numbers...

Comment: I believe it is about the recently discussed [capacitor paradox](http://www.users.on.net/~ithilien/tam/electronics/CapacitorParadox.html). https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/337487/a-capacitor-stores-half-the-energy-when-charged-from-a-battery-each-and-every-ti/337493#comment796503_337493

Comment: Anyway, look [here](http://www.smpstech.com/charge.htm) at the "solvability" section.

Comment: Me thinks your numbers only apply if you completely discharge and recharge each time. Which for a battery results in buying a new one...

Comment: @Eugene Sh. You nailed it, that is the question that got me thinking about this, and I just knew I was missing a key concept, thank you

Comment: @EugeneSh. there is something off about that energy paradox thing. I have a circuit that sucks the charge out of one cap and puts it into another cap of the same size and it ends up in the high 90s efficiency wise. SO unless I'm breaking some law of physics somewhere....

Comment: @Trevor I bet you have some other than just capacitors stuff in this circuit

Comment: @EugeneSh. not much just an inductor a mosfet a diode and some control logic.

Comment: @Trevor That's pretty much :) Especially the inductor and control logic.

Comment: Ya but nothing that adds energy, and it ought to have MORE losses than just hooking the two caps together.

Comment: @Trevor Are you serious now? If you are, please go over the calculations and the mentioned question. This "paradox" is real.

Comment: @EugeneSh.  yes I am serious. I know the math says it is real.. but I suspect something else is going on...

Comment: @Trevor Nothing, really. When charging a cap with a resistance, half of the energy is going for heating. Without a resistance and other elements the circuit is not physical and is giving a singularity. So no magic here. With an inductor the things are becoming physical and making sense.

Comment: @EugeneSh. hmmm...

Comment: @Trevor You need some element to "absorb" the "sudden" voltage change on the cap. It can be a resistor, but then it will "waste" the energy. Or it can be the inductor, it will store it.

Comment: @EugeneSh. that's fine but again, in my charge pump, I'd still have the same if not more losses...

Comment: @Trevor Charge pumps are never letting the caps to drain completely. So the "sudden" voltage change is much smaller than in the "paradox" case, so less energy is wasted

Comment: @EugeneSh. hmmm...  I'm getting a headache... LOL

Comment: @EugeneSh. anyhoos.. here are the curves from my pump just for your interest. https://i.stack.imgur.com/3O3wT.png Note max energy in coil is when both caps are at half charge. I'm still not convinced about how the time should change the total losses though.

Comment: @EugeneSh. My gut tells me it's more complex. Something like, cap to cap you are allowing the energy stored in an electric field to dissipate into space via the magnetic field created by the movement of the electrons. In the charge pump I am adding sufficient inductance to make that field hang around long enough to re-use it.. AT least that sort of explains the evidence.

Comment: @Trevor *field hang around long enough to re-use it* - that what I meant by "store energy" by inductor :)

Comment: That's broken logic, or you are doing something small, or something wrong.  The in-out efficiency of large batteries is well known to solar homepower types, and it is more like 90% except during worst case conditions such as finish charging.   50% would be thermodynamically impossible; the batteries are huge jars of mostly electrolyte, packed tight, giving them very poor heat-radiation ability. At 50% efficiency they would need huge active cooling to keep them at sane working temp.    Heat damages batteries.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not at all, for batteries that approximate capacitor behaviour (Which is to say nearly none of them) you charge with a current source not a voltage source, which is potentially very efficient.

Batteries that behave as a voltage source in series with a resistor (Where the resistor value appears to vary) you charge with a current limited constant voltage.

Now on discharge, maximum power transfer occurs when RSource = RLoad, but we don't want maximum power! We want (somewhat close to) maximum energy, so we make sure the batteries internal resistance is much smaller then the apparent resistance of the load.

Comment: I knew I was missing a key concept here, and the way you answered has filled it in for me.